# Print a string sent via pointer C

Tags: c, dynamic, vector, struct, printf

I have this struct

```
Cheltuieli * creeaza(int numar_apartament,int suma,char * tipul){
    Cheltuieli * cheltuiala=malloc(sizeof(Cheltuieli));
    cheltuiala->numar_apartament=numar_apartament;
    cheltuiala->suma=suma;
    cheltuiala->tipul=tipul;
    return cheltuiala;
}
```

which should act "like a class" and i have this method

```
char* get_tipul(Cheltuieli c){
    char * tip_de_returnat=strdup(c.tipul);
    return tip_de_returnat;
}
```

Which supposed to be a "getter" for the tipul

I have a generic container

```
typedef void* Elements;

typedef struct{
    Elements * Element;
    int lungimea;
    int capacitatea;

} vector_dinamic;
```

that stores Elements and acts like a dynamic vector, my elements are Cheltuieli

The problem is here, I have this function that supposed to print all the elements of a dynamic vector, it prints the "numar_apartament" and "suma" correctly but at "tipul" i get an upside-down "?"

```
void afiseaza(controller * ctr){
    int i;
    Cheltuieli *c;
    for (i=0;i<ctr->repo->v->lungimea;i++)
    {  
        c=ctr->repo->v->Element[i];
        printf("Numar apartament: %d\n",get_numar_apartament(*c));
        printf("Suma: %d\n",get_suma(*c));
        printf("Tipul: %s\n",get_tipul(*c));

    }
```

Could someone help me out ? Thank you!

Comment: are all your char arrays null terminated?`\0`

Comment: Without seeing the entire program I can't be sure, but this is *likely* to be a case of strings getting used after they are freed. Try moving the `strdup(tipul)` from `get_tipul` to `creeaza`.

Comment: I think if you write code in English will make things better.

Comment: i read them with scanf so i suppose they are null terminated .... Yousf sorry but it is for school I normally do not do that but i have to now @Zack , thanks, that was the problem !

Comment: print the string inside the getter function, to verify that it's getting proper data. By the way, it's highly un-orthodox C for a string getter to create a dynamically allocated copy. It would be more "normal" to declare the getter to return `const char *` and just return the pointer. Further, you're doing a lot of by-value calls with structs, which is also somewhat confusing and could be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

"tipul" is from "Cheltuieli * creeaza(int numar_apartament,int suma,char * tipul)". When you call creeaza(), what did you pass as "tipul"? For example, if you pass a function local char array to creeaza, when you do printf, the local char array might have already been released. So you should check what kind of string you pass to creeaza() as "tupil".

By the way, for this function "char* get_tipul(Cheltuieli c)", you'd better change it to:

```
char* get_tipul(const Cheltuieli *c)
```

This way avoid create a temp copy of c.